# How to calculate the distance of a data point to a decision hyperplane created by svm using e1071

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, distance

I used the e1071 package to create a linear model that predicts 2 classes. I now am able to predict classes, but I also want to know the distance of each prediction to the decision hyperplane.

This code subsets the iris data, creates a training set and a prediction set:

```
# The data should have 2 factors, such that there is only 1 hyperplane
iris.subset <- subset(iris, iris$Species %in% c("versicolor", "virginica"))
iris.subset$Species <- as.factor(as.character(iris.subset$Species))
# Random sampling for training data
training.data <- iris.subset[sample(1:nrow(iris.subset), 50, replace=FALSE),]
# Remaining samples make up the prediction data
prediction.data <- iris.subset[!(rownames(iris.subset) %in% rownames(training.data)),]
```

This code fits the model.:

```
require(e1071)
svmfit <- svm(Species~., data=training.data, kernel="linear")
```

Predicting 5 samples from the prediction set:

```
predict(svmfit, prediction.data[sample(1:nrow(prediction.data), 5, replace=FALSE),])
```

This gave me the classes. Now, I want to calculate the distance of these points to the hyperplane. How do I do that?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450609/distance-between-a-point-and-the-hyperplane-in-svm-matlab) is an unanswered question of the same sort, but in Matlab.
[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/interpreting-distance-from-hyperplane-in-svm) is another page that might be of help, but again in Matlab.

Comment: Yes! I can't get information on the `decision.value` argument with `?predict`, though. Where can I read the documentation on this?

Comment: `predict()` is a generic function. You can see all the "special" versions with `methods(predict)`. If you run `class(svmfit)` you can see what special cases it will trigger. In this case if you bring up the help for `?predict.svm` you will see where that parameter is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the decision values from the predict with

```
dd <- prediction.data[sample(1:nrow(prediction.data), 5, replace=FALSE),]
pred <- predict(svmfit, dd, decision.value=T)
pred 
#        112        139         87        108         70 
#  virginica  virginica versicolor  virginica versicolor 
# attr(,"decision.values")
#     virginica/versicolor
# 112            1.9830355
# 139            0.4160704
# 87            -1.2680673
# 108            2.7181950
# 70            -2.6954507
```

These values are returned in an attribute. You can access the data more directly with

```
attr(pred, "decision.values")
```

which returns a matrix of values.

For more information, you can read the help page for `?predict.svm`